# Ajax POST / XML not working

Tags: javascript, xml, ajax, post

I have two buttons I press. one calls function with argument of "1" the other calls with argument of "2"

```
function getOptions(scheme){
    var url = "http://localhost/AV/data2.php";
    var XMLHttpRequestObject = new XMLHttpRequest();
    XMLHttpRequestObject.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (this.readyState != 4) return;
        if (this.status == 200){ 
            var xmlDocument = this.responseXML;
            options = xmlDocument.getElementsByTagName("option");
            listOptions();
        }
    }
    XMLHttpRequestObject.open("POST", url, true);
    XMLHttpRequestObject.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    XMLHttpRequestObject.send("scheme="+scheme);
    //XMLHttpRequestObject.send(null);
}
```

and the data2.php file:

```
<?php
    header("Content-type: text/xml");
    if ($_POST["scheme"=="1"]) $options = array('black','pink','orange');
    if ($_POST["scheme"=="2"]) $options = array('red','blue','green');
    //$options = array('red','blue','green');
    echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>";
    echo '<options>';
    foreach ($options as $value)
    {
        echo '<option>';
        echo $value;
        echo '</option>';
    }
    echo '</options>';
?>
```

this does not work.. it returns something about "junk after document element".. I have other parts in there i commented out and those work when i change it to GET but why doesn't this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be

```
if ($_POST["scheme"]=="1")   // and
if ($_POST["scheme"]=="2")
```

Comment: derp. I can not believe this mess. years ago I did not make mistakes like this. I've been out of the game for far too long this is embarrassing heh. thanks Andrew

Comment: well i did after i saw the red squiggles and right clicked it :p